# Policy error: undefined method id for nil:nilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a policy that's giving me trouble. I keep getting the error message

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

for the following policy:

```
def update?
    user.present? && current_user.creator?(record, current_user)
end
```

This is the method user.creator?:

```
def creator?(wiki, user)
    relationships.find_by(wiki_id: wiki.id, user_id: user.id).creator_created
end
```

Relationships is the join table in a has_many, through relationship between Wikis and Users. Neither Wiki nor User is nil, and Relationships shouldn't be, either. I've just seeded the database to include a Relationships record for each Wiki. When there's no User, this policy works just fine, it simply rejects whatever I've put underneath. This error only occurs when there *is* a user, in other words when I'm logged in as a user. So I just can't tell which class is reading as nil, and which id is a problem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you test this code by putting 2 lines beforehand: one that only gets wiki.id to print out, and another that only gets user.id to print out.  Then you can isolate "wiki" and "user" by line and find out exactly which one has the problem.

Comment: @Ellenw I think the `record` you are sending through `update` method is `nil` Which value you are sending to `record` object

Comment: That's a good question! record should equal wiki, which is the argument I send to the policy. I've tried using "wiki" instead of record, but I get the same error. How can I send a value to record?

Comment: Show us the complete controller action where you are making this call.

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` may not be available in the policy, that's often a controller helper method provided by Devise.

Comment: I've initialized a "user" at the beginning of my policy file, and tried just using user instead of current_user, and I get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted, this looks like Pundit for authorizations. In Pundit, `current_user` is not the current user, `user` **is** the current user as it is passed through when using the `authorize` method (I assume that you defined `user` in your policy class as the user, if not, use the defined variable for the user). Read the [Pundit docs](https://github.com/elabs/pundit/blob/master/README.md) for more information.

Replace `current_user` with `user` and you won't get that error. If you are looking to do something special with the authorization, post a comment with what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, for some reason, I get the same error if I use user as if I use current_user. I may be using the policy in an unsupported way. I've got it in an "if" clause in an index view.

Comment: Post the controller action up to and including the `authorize` line.

Comment: Please post the entire policy too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was calling the policy on examples that had no relationship record, so Relationship was nil. I've edited my creator? method to:

```
def collaborator?(wiki, user)
    if Relationship.exists?(:wiki_id =>wiki.id, :user_id => user.id)
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

and that seems to have helped. Thank you for your input!